# Meteor, include boostrap only an spefic route ? e.g. /admin

Tags: meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to use

- https://github.com/yogiben/meteor-admin

which requires

- https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap

But my "client" application doesn't use twitter bootstrap, would it be possible to install `meteor add twbs:bootstrap` but only include it on my "admin" "layout"?